# Kind of wpf binding

Tags: wpf

ı try to bind model to xml.I am so new at wpf. But ı can not use this syntax. It gives error. It is "member local is not recognized or is not accessible "

```
<Grid local:GridHelpers.RowCount="{Binding RowCount}"
      local:GridHelpers.ColumnCount="{Binding ColumnCount}" />
```

how can ı convert this syntax. It is xaml

I try this.but this is not work.

```
<Grid>
    <ContentPresenter
            Name="--"  
          Content="{Binding ElementName=RowCount, Path=?}">
    </ContentPresenter>
</Grid>
```

my xmal class same this example: https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: ı try to binding ı look this example. But this binding not work for me https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/

Comment: have you added Local as xmlns ? in your xaml ?

Comment: please post your entire xaml class

Comment: it is same as ı sended link. It is same

Comment: I coulndnt see any xaml file in it? there is just a grid definition

Answer (score 0):

You need to add GridHelper class to your project and add that namespace to your xaml file, then you can refer to it.

as of now it is complaining about that compiler can not understand what is Local namespace.

Comment: Project has GridHelper class .

Comment: is the namespace to this class added in your xaml ? paste your entire xaml

Comment: yes, it is. I look this example. My classes nearly same this [link](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/)

Answer (score 0):

add your xml namespace declaration to topmost element (e.g Window or UserControl)

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

just replace WpfApplication1 with namespace of GridHelper class:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class GridHelper...
}
```